# Unable to find duplicate list in "todo list" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, duplicates

My JS code:-
it's been just 1 month learning JS, so pls help me out.

Here inside `addItems` function I wrote a for-loop to check duplicate list with the help of textContent of list and input value of input text box. But it's not working.

[image]

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var element = document.querySelector("#todo-list");
var children = element.childElementCount;
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var input = document.querySelector("input");

btn.addEventListener("click", addItems);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(event.key == "Enter")
    {
        addItems();
    }
});

function addItems()
{
    if(input.value == "")
    {
        alert("Empty List cannot be created");
    }

    else{
        var list = document.createElement("li");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(input.value);
        children++;
        list.appendChild(textNode);

        element.appendChild(list);
        console.log(children);

        //This loop is not working properly after adding new list
        for(var i=0; i<children; i++)
        {
            if(li[i].textContent == input.value){
               alert("Duplicate List");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, I'd change what you're doing here. I would add an item to an items array and check it for duplicates and then render it. React is really good at this if you're interested in learning more stuff. You can also use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to guarantee no duplicates.

Comment: Thank You @Matt for your suggestions, React is something far away from me bcoz I've just dived into JS recently.

Comment: Yeah, set can also solve this but, I want to get it via for-loop only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to access the `<ul>` element with the ID of `todo-list`.

You should also use `===` (triple-equals) instead of `==`. This checks the type and value.

Also, You can access the children using `list.childNodes`. You could also call `forEach` using:

```js
list.forEach((child) => {
  if (child.textContent === input.value) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

**Update:** Added a delete button for each list item.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const list = document.querySelector("#todo-list");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

btn.addEventListener("click", addItems);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    addItems();
  }
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("btn-delete")) {
    event.target.closest("li").remove();
  }
});

function addItems() {
  if (input.value === "") {
    alert("Empty item cannot be added");
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (list.childNodes[i].textContent === input.value) {
        alert("Duplicate item");
        return; // Exit function, do not proceed
      }
    }
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    li.append(textNode);
    const btnDelete = document.createElement("i");
    btnDelete.classList.add('btn-delete');
    li.append(btnDelete);
    list.appendChild(li);
    input.value = ""; // Clear value
  }
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ADD8E6;
  gap: 1rem;
}

body > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

#todo-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#todo-list li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.667rem;
  min-width: 20rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.btn-delete {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 40%);
  color: #D44;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.btn-delete:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Item name..." />
  <button type="button">Add Item</button>
</div>
<ul id="todo-list">
  <li>Hello<i class="btn-delete"></i></li>
  <li>World<i class="btn-delete"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this method works fine when I've only list element, because today I added delete button aside the list, this code didn't work.

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide I added a delete button.

Comment: how the deletion is happening here? 
<br/> Can't we add a delete button instead on an icon.

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide you could, just swap the `<i>` with a `<button>`. Showing a button with the text "delete" next to each item is a waste of screen real estate. Showing an icon or glyph is more succinct.

Comment: Once again Thanks a lot @Mr. Polywhirl for helping me out in these hard times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array some method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const isDuplicate = li.some(item => item.textContent == input.value);
if (isDuplicate) {
    alert("Duplicate List");
    return
}
```

Comment: What if I want to achieve this only by using for-loop?

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide Sure, you can return or break for-loop after getting a duplicate item

Comment: But the thing is I was doing it by `li[i].textContent == input.value` which didn't work

Answer (score 0):

because you load your list once, when the code is reading, then, your list content in the element var stay empty. you need to reload your list each time to have an updated list. Just move

```
var element = document.querySelector("#todo-list");
```

into `addItem` function

Comment: This didn't work